# Convergence of growing sequences of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

For each $T \in \mathbb{N}$ I have a sequence of $T$ random variables: $(\hat{z}_1, \dots, \hat{z}_T)$. When $T \to \infty$ these sequences are "more and more looking like sequences if independent standard normal variables". To formalize the latter condition I have two ideas:

1. For any fixed $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $\hat{z}_i = \hat{z}_i(T) \to z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. In other words, for any fixed index, I have convergence to standard normal variable when $T$ is growing;
2. $\text{max}_i \left( \left| \mathbb{P}\{\hat{z}_i \in A_T\} - \mathbb{P}\{z_i \in A_T\} \right| \right) \to 0$, when $T \to \infty$. Here $z_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $\hat{z}_i = \hat{z}_i(T)$.

**Problem:** Prove that for any sequence of sets $A_T \subset \mathbb{R}^T$ the following convergence takes place:
$$
\left|
    \mathbb{P} 
    \left( 
       [\hat{z}_1, \dots, \hat{z}_T] \in A_T 
    \right)
    -
    \mathbb{P} 
    \left( 
       [z_1, \dots, z_T] \in A_T 
    \right)
\right|
\to 0, \quad T \to \infty,
$$
Here again $z_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $\hat{z}_i = \hat{z}_i(T)$.

**My thoughts:**

1. Since lengths of sequences are growing, I cannot apply classic techniques...
2. I was trying to bound this difference of probabilities with probability of "coordinates", but I do not know how to reduce this problem to problem in coordinates...

I would be very grateful for any ideas.